# Assembly in IA-32 and x86-64 POP instruction

Tags: assembly

What does `pop ebp` mean in an IA-32 and x86-64 machines, at the end before a `ret` (return) instruction of code? So I do have old and new `ebp`, and the new `ebp` is pushed into the stack by a call of a function. Then this `ebp` is `pop`'ed? How does the `pop` instruction changes the value of `ebp`?

Comment: It is part of the function epilogue in almost any code.  It is simply restores the stack frame pointer so it again points to the stack frame of the caller.  Well covered in any book about x86 assembly programming.

Comment: how does it change the value of ebp?

Answer (score 2):

```
PUSH EAX
```

Essentially means:

```
SUB ESP,4
MOV [ESP],EAX
```

And

```
POP EAX
```

Means:

```
MOV EAX,[ESP]
ADD ESP,4
```

---

When you talk about old and new `EBP` I guess you're referring to the function prologues and epilogues?

```
PUSH EBP     ; Store caller's EBP on the stack
MOV EBP,ESP  ; Set EBP to the current stack pointer

; Here we can do things like:
MOV EAX,[EBP+8]
PUSH EAX
MOV EBX,[EBP+12]
POP EAX
; ..to access the stack. Since we've got a fixed reference point for
; the stack in EBP we don't have to worry about the stack pointer
; changing.

; For example, we could do this instead to access the same stack
; elements as above:
MOV EAX,[ESP+8]
PUSH EAX
MOV EBX,[ESP+16]
POP EAX
; But notice that we had to change the second offset since the push
; instruction changed the stack pointer. It's obviously easier to deal
; with a base address that doesn't change every time we execute
; certain instructions.

MOV ESP,EBP  ; Restore the stack pointer
POP EBP      ; Restore the caller's EBP before returning
```